# Report Builder paramter dropdown to choose column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a parameter with the available values as column names and a I am using that parameter in the sql query

```
 WHERE ((@ColumnName) BETWEEN (@StartDate) AND (@EndDate)) 
AND (schema.table.column_name LIKE (@Number))
```

When i try to run the report i get a cannot convert date/time from characters

[image]

If i remove the @ColumnName parameter the report runs fine but i want the ability to choose a column to search the date against.

Comment: You can't use a variable (`@ColumnName`) to represent a column name.  SQL appears to be interpreting it as a "string" literal in this case (whatever data type the variable is).  You'll need to use dynamic tsql.

Comment: Indeed that is happening but looking to see what the best practice for using dynamic on this.

Comment: There are two common server-side options for creating and executing dynamic tsql strings: [EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) and [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want pass Column name dynamically you will need to use a stored procedure to do this using dynamic sql something like this....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_Data
  @ColumnName1  SYSNAME,
  @ColumnName2  SYSNAME,
  @StartDate    DATETIME,
  @EndDate      DATETIME,
  @Number       VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM TableName'
         + N'WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName1) + N' BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate '
         + N' AND ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName2) + N' LIKE ''@Number'' '

 EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL 
                      ,N'@StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME, @Number VARCHAR(100)'
                      ,@StartDate
                      ,@EndDate
                      ,@Number

END
```